# Делаю сайт, проблема с футром

Tags: html, css

Делаю сайт (учусь). На главной странице с ним все хорошо (1 скрин), а вот на других страницах он очень высоко. Можно же сделать как-то, чтобы он везде был внизу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
footer {
  width: 98%;
  float: left;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border-top: 2px solid silver;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

footer #social {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

footer #social img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  float: left;
}

footer #rights {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="social">
    <a href="https://vk.com/infoeetk" title "Группа в ВК" target="_blank">
      <image src="image/VK.png" alt="Вконтакте" title="Вконтакте">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="rights">
    Все права защищены 2019 &copy
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: [прижать footer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=прижать+footer)